# Алгоритм определения даты полнолуния.

Tags: алгоритм, календарь

Захотелось сделать календарь полнолуний. Но вот только как их высчитывать не знаю.
Есть ли какие-нибудь готовые алгоритмы?

Comment: А просто поиск по "расчет фаз Луны" не задался?

Мне на первый взгляд вот эта ссылка:

    http://web.archive.org/web/20080504163207/http://home.att.net/~srschmitt/lunarphasecalc.html

 понравилась.

Answer (score 2):

В PHP кстати уже есть готовая функция easter_day
Такую же функцию можно написать используя [Алгоритм Гаусса для расчета Пасхи](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%93%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B_%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%85%D0%B8) , а дальше плясать от этого добавляя к первому полнолунию один лунный месяц.
А вот здесь http://nabasice.narod2.ru/ есть готовые программы реализованные на QBasic